# SQL count with sub-query running slow in Ms SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL query using count statement and contains the left join between 2 tables.

But, the query was running quite slow and result appear in 5-10 minutes per query.

Hope anyone can help to improve the performance with below query that I am working on.

```
    select origin,count(*) as shipmentcount,
    (select count(*) as unprocessed  from tblshipmentdetail sd
    left join tblshipmentprocess sp on 
    sd.airbillno=sp.airbillno 
    where sp.airbillno is null and 
    sd.pickupdate >='2016-01-01' and sd.pickupdate <='2016-01-31'
    and sd.origin=a.origin
    ) as unprocessed
    from tblshipmentdetail a
    where pickupdate >='2016-01-01' and pickupdate <='2016-01-31'
    group by origin
```

Comment: Can you post the query plan?

Comment: this query will take around 20 minutes to run ad get the result.

Comment: there are 3 columns in this query : origin, count() as shipmentcount, count() as unprocessed. Both count will count the number of origin based on the airbillno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation instead of correlated queries :

```
    select origin,count(*) as shipmentcount,
           count(case when sp.airbillno is null then 1 end) as unprocessed
    from tblshipmentdetail a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tblshipmentprocess sp
     ON(a.airbillno=sp.airbillno)
    where a.pickupdate >='2016-01-01' and a.pickupdate <='2016-01-31'
    group by a.origin
```

Comment: Hi, the query have an error, for the origin column line 1

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, this may help you

```
select origin,SUM(1) as shipmentcount,SUM(CASE WHEN sp.airbillno is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) unprocessed
from tblshipmentdetail sd
left join tblshipmentprocess sp on  sd.airbillno=sp.airbillno 
where pickupdate >='2016-01-01' and pickupdate <='2016-01-31'
group by origin
```

Comment: That is exactly the same as mine but with sum!

Comment: Yes you are rgt , @sagi

Comment: hi, but i need count. if sum not valid for this query.

Comment: Hi, Count(*) or Sum(1) - both will get the same result here. Also u can include required columns in group by or where clause.

Comment: I have tested this updated query but the result was different.